# PoweShell script to click HTML button and fill-up form

Tags: html, powershell, automation

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm trying to use the following script to login to a page and fill up a form.

```
$username = "user";
$password = "12345";
$loginUrl = "https://demobrasil5.educamos.com/";
$iterator = 1;

#initialize browser
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($loginUrl);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle

#login
($ie.document.getElementById("NombreUsuario") |select -first 1).value = $username;
($ie.document.getElementById("Clave") |select -first 1).value = $password;
($ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-acceder") |select -first 1).click();
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle

#navigate to page and click Create
$ie.navigate("https://demobrasil5.educamos.com/DatosCentro/Usuarios");
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle
($ie.document.getElementById("btncrearalumno") |select -first 1).click();
```

But for the life of me, I can't seem to make this work. This is the HMTL of the page:

```
<div class="iconos" id="btncrearalumno"><a data-btnbehaviour="link" data-btnmultiple="true" data-btnrequerido="false" data-resizable="False" href="/DatosCentro/Alumnos/CrearAlumno?calendarioescolarId=29d0c494-fb65-4654-8ed2-27461f346e0c&amp;TabActual=0"><span class="glyphBoton_anadir glyphBotones"></span><p>Criar</p></a></div>
```

I would deeply appreciate any kind of help with this.

Comment: Difficult to reproduce without a real credentials. Anyways, you might just pull the `href` attribute and `$ie.navigate(...` further which is probably also faster and more stable.

Comment: As a side note: it is a best practice to [Avoid Using Semicolons (`;`) as Line Terminators](https://poshcode.gitbooks.io/powershell-practice-and-style/content/Style-Guide/Code-Layout-and-Formatting.html) in PowerShell.

Comment: @iRon, thank you for replying! How would I proceed to get the href from the HTML? Sorry if my question is fundamental, I'm pretty new at PowerShell.
And thanks for the tip with the Semicolons!

Comment: It is actually concerns more [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_htmldom.asp) than PowerShell. Anyways, I guess it should just be: `$ie.document.getElementById("btncrearalumno").href`

Comment: I'm going to try that. Thanks again!!

Comment: @iRon, I couldn't get it to work. Any other ideas?